# Flask + Gunicorn in Ubuntu Container, no connection

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I have a flask+gunicorn server, running on an ubuntu docker image (`ubuntu:18.04`)

In docker-compose I have this:

```
  python_server:
    build: ./python_server/
    image: flask-server:${PYTHON_SERVER_VERSION}
    command:
      [
        "gunicorn",
        "-b",
        "0.0.0.0:8080",
        "wsgi:app",
        "--workers",
        "9",
        "--worker-class",
        "gevent",
        "--worker-connections",
        "1000",
      ]
    expose:
      - "8080"


------ OTHER CONTAINERS THAT USE THIS ONE HERE -------------
```

When I try to open the port in the `Dockerfile` (`RUN ufw allow 8080`) I get:

> ufw not found

Other containers can't connect to it, in Node getting:

```
error: Error: write ECONNRESET
     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:789:14)

forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
      write ECONNRESET
```

and I don't see any connections in the log

Is this a firewall issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. The `ufw` command is unnecessary, just remove it.
2. You're missing port forwarding. "expose", as per the documentation, will "expose ports without publishing them to the host machine."

What you want is:

```yaml
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

Instead of the `expose` section.

To understand a bit about why you need port forwarding, see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Comment: This is the behavior I'm looking for, I only need this container to be seen by my other containers which is what `expose` is for. But they can't access it which I figure means the ubuntu container is blocking the port